# Possible targeting SendInput()?

Tags: c#, user32

Using SendInput() to send long keystrokes in C#. The problem is that when using it, it works on all programs when called. Is it possible targeting it to work only on a specific program? Like in PostMessage() that uses FindWindow.

My SendInput():

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
    internal static extern uint SendInput(
        uint nInputs,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray), In] INPUT[] pInputs,
        int cbSize);

    public void KeySend(VirtualKeyShort key)
    {
        INPUT[] Inputs = new INPUT[1];
        INPUT Input = new INPUT();

        Input.type = 1;
        Input.U.ki.wVk = key;
        Inputs[0] = Input;


        SendInput(1, Inputs, INPUT.Size);
    }

    public void KeyUp(VirtualKeyShort key)
    {
        INPUT[] Inputs = new INPUT[1];
        INPUT Input = new INPUT();

        Input.type = 1; 
        Input.U.ki.wVk = key;
        Input.U.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF.KEYUP;
        Inputs[0] = Input;


        SendInput(1, Inputs, INPUT.Size);
    }
```

Thank you.

Comment: The whole point of `SendInput` is to re-use the OS input processing logic.  That logic includes respecting the focus.  If you don't want to respect the focus, you shouldn't ask to use the logic that does.

Answer (score 0):

before launching your sendinput you could do that (for example) if you want to send key to notepad :

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        var proc = Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad");
        if (proc.Length > 0) {
            SetForegroundWindow(proc[0].MainWindowHandle);
        }
    }
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);
```

}

your window app will  have the focus and can receive the keys

you could use EnumWindows if you want to enumerate all application